# return mvcjqgrid gridsettings to action controller by jquery post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Good Day Everyone, I'm using MvcJqGrid(https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/MvcJqGrid) to display my data in my project. I'm trying to pass the current jqgrid settings by jquery post, but i am not able to get it in the action controller. it seems I'm missing something for the GridModelBinder. can you tell me what am i doing wrong here.. thanks

This is my javascript code:

```
function Export() {
        var data = $("#ReportGrid").getGridParam("postData");
        $.post('/Home/ExporttoExcel', { gridSettings: data, moduleID: 3 });
}
```

and this is my action controller:

```
public FileContentResult ExporttoExcel(GridSettings gridSettings, Int32 moduleID = 0)
        {

///Do something with the gridsettings value here.

var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var fileContent = encoding.GetBytes(file.ToString());
            return File(fileContent, "application/ms-excel", "List.xls");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this one by just passing the search values from the jqgrid and deserialize it in the controller.

my javascript looks like this:

```
function ajaxExport() {
        var data = $("#ReportGrid").getGridParam("postData");
        location.href = "/Home/ExporttoExcel?issearch=" + data._search + "&where=" + data.filters;

    }
```

my Action method:

```
public ActionResult ExporttoExcel(String issearch, String where = "")
{
var jserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

GridSettings settings = new GridSettings();

                if (where != "")
                {
                    MvcJqGrid.Filter f = jserializer.Deserialize<MvcJqGrid.Filter>(where);
                    settings = new GridSettings()
                    {
                        IsSearch = issearch == "true" ? true : false,
                        PageIndex = 1,
                        PageSize = 10000,
                        SortColumn = "",
                        SortOrder = "asc",
                        Where = new MvcJqGrid.Filter()
                        {
                            groupOp = f.groupOp,
                            rules = f.rules

                        }
                    };


                }

//Do my stuff here. Use the where conditions to query my DB
}
```